# How do I force a DNS resolution in python grpc?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, grpc, grpc-python

I use the python grpcio package to connect to a grpc service via host name something like this:

```
credentials = grpc.composite_channel_credentials(channel_credentials, call_credentials)

return grpc.aio.secure_channel(domain, credentials)
```

Many (over 1000) channels are created during the scripts life time (on purpose).

the service is load balanced and resolves to multiple IP addresses.
I frequently run into the issue, that during the scripts' startup DNS resolution is done only once, one of the IP addresses is picked and all requests are being sent to that one IP address leading to denial of service.
How can I force a truly random DNS resolution every time I create a channel so ideally every IP address is hit equally?

I found this document about grpc load balancing, but it doesn't seem to have actionable information about solving the problem: https://grpc.io/blog/grpc-load-balancing/

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things that could be going on here:

##### Long DNS TTLs

If you're running this script on a distro like Ubuntu, it's likely that you've got a DNS cache running on localhost intercepting all of your DNS requests. If the TTL is long and the set of backends is changing, then you won't be responsive to scale-up events.

##### The default [Pick First](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/b3fb266937af1be90b2aa7cfe25333b4d6f7bb9a/doc/load-balancing.md#pick_first) LB algorithm is biting you

gRPC has a concept of *subchannel*. Each channel created by the surface API corresponds to one or more subchannels and each subchannel corresponds to an actual TCP connection. Subchannels are shared between multiple physical channels based on the target name. When a channel is created, DNS resolution for the host name is performed. For each address returned in the DNS response, if there is already a subchannel for that address, the channel uses it. If there isn't, it will start a new subchannel for it.

After that, the default Pick First LB policy kicks in. If there is already an active subchannel, the library will select that subchannel to send the RPC. So if there is overlap in the lifetime of your channels (or even near overlap -- subchannels stay alive for a while after there are outstanding RPCs on them), you would expect to see only one subchannel being used and therefore only one backend being hit.

Instead, you could use the [round robin LB policy](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/b3fb266937af1be90b2aa7cfe25333b4d6f7bb9a/doc/load-balancing.md#round_robin) like in [this example](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/b3fb266937af1be90b2aa7cfe25333b4d6f7bb9a/examples/python/lb_policies/greeter_client.py#L25). This would ensure that, at least on a single channel, RPCs will be distributed between all of the backends. However, if you send only one RPC per channel, you may need randomization of the order of the addresses in your DNS response in order to make things work. In general, I would recommend re-using your channels if at all possible to avoid that issue.